# Auth error when trying to send an email via SSL

Tags: go, ssl, smtp, tls1.2, postfix-mta

I run an email server **to which  a desktop client is able to connect to and send email with no issue,** via SSL/TLS. However, I haven't been to do it in Go using **the same credentials**.

```
import (
    
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/mail"
    "net/smtp"
    "os"
    "crypto/tls"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func init() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    smtpHost = os.Getenv("EMAIL_SERVER_SMTP_HOST")

    //465
    smtpPort = os.Getenv("EMAIL_SERVER_SMTP_PORT")
    //.........
}

func sendEmail(to mail.Address, subject string, body string) (string, error) {
    headers := make(map[string]string)
    newUuid, err := uuid.NewRandom()
    headers["Message-ID"] = newUuid.String()
    headers["From"] = from.String()
    headers["To"] = to.String()
    headers["Subject"] = subject

    // Setup message
    message := ""
    for k, v := range headers {
        message += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
    }

    message += "\r\n" + body
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", userLogin, userPassword, smtpHost)

    // TLS config
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
        ServerName:         smtpHost,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", serverName, tlsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, smtpHost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    //!!! error here
    if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    //.........

    c.Quit()
    return msgId, nil
}
```

Error

```
panic: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
```

In the logs of a server there's been no additional information other than this.

All the credentials get read from ".env" correctly.

What's the matter?